# Cannot read property 'createMessageCollector' of undefined, was working and i changed nothing and now its broken, how can i fix?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

ok so im making a Discord <-> Roblox bot for ranking and verification and some other stuff and my verification command broke after i tried to change something, all i tried to do was chack the database before it ran any of the other code to check of the user was already verified but it broke the command so i undid everything i changed and now in getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\commands\verify.js:50
 const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: '1', maxMatches: "1", time: 
"200000" }) //This is the collector to collect the Message for getting the username.
                                ^
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessageCollector' of undefined
   at Object.execute (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\commands\verify.js:50:37)
   at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\index.js:78:40)
    ←[90m    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
     at MessageCreateAction.handle 
    (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\actions\ 
   MessageCreate.js: 
   31:14)
   at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\ 
  ←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAG 
   E_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules 
←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket 




   (    C:\Users\Owner\Desktop 
 \ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard. 
  js:444:22)
  at WebSocketShard.onMessage 
   (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\ 
   websocket\WebSocketShard. 
  js:301:10)
  at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\event- 
target.js:125:16)
←[90m    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
←[90m    at Receiver.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
at Receiver.dataMessage 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
at Receiver.getData 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
at Receiver.startLoop 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
at Receiver._write 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
←[90m    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:442:12)←[39m
←[90m    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:426:5)←[39m
←[90m    at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:317:11)←[39m
at TLSSocket.socketOnData 
(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ClanSystems\node_modules\←[4mws←[24m\lib\websocket.js:872:35)
←[90m    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
←[90m    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)←[39m
←[90m    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)←[39m
←[90m    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)←[39m
←[90m    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)←[39m
```

can someone please help me fix it?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const rbx = require("noblox.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("../config.json");

//CONNECT TO DATABASE
mongoose.connect(config.mongoPass, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

//Access userdata model

const userdata = require("../Models/userdata.js");

//verify code
module.exports = {
  name: "verify",
  description: "does thing",
  execute(message, args) {
    function makeid() {
      var text = "";
      var selectFruit = [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "☁️",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        " ",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "☀️",
        "⛅️",
        "☔️",
        "",
      ];
      // Emoji list This can be used for words.
      text += selectFruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectFruit.length)];
      text += selectFruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectFruit.length)]; // This will random the
      emojis;
      text += selectFruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectFruit.length)];
      text += selectFruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectFruit.length)];
      return text;
    }

    const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
      max: "1",
      maxMatches: "1",
      time: "200000",
    }); //This is the collector to collect the Message for getting the username.
    const robloxEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("0x00e5ff")
      .setTitle("verification Started...")
      .setDescription(" What's your ROBLOX username?")
      .setFooter(
        "This prompt will cancel after 200 seconds.",
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/686639712869285946.gif?v=1"
      )
      .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(robloxEmbed).then((sentMessage) => {
      //Send the first Embed

      collector.on("collect", (m) => {
        if (m.content === "cancel" || m.content === "Cancel") {
          const cancelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0x00e5ff)
            .setTitle("Verification canceled")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(
              "ClanSystems bot for group promotions",
              "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755083118087766056/755139240232485035/no.gif"
            );
          sentMessage.edit(cancelEmbed);
          return;
        } //Collector1 End
        rbx.getIdFromUsername(m.content).then((foundId) => {
          //Get the userID from username
          const Id = foundId;
          const newString =
            makeid() + makeid() + makeid() + makeid() + makeid(); //Emoji thing
          const foundUsername = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("0x00e5ff")
            .setTitle("Step 2")
            .setDescription(
              "Hello **" +
                m.content +
                "**, to verify that you are that user. Please put this in your blurb, or status. \n `" +
                newString +
                "`\n\nSay **done** when complete.\nSay **cancel** to cancel. "
            )
            .setFooter("Player ID is " + foundId)
            .setTimestamp();
          sentMessage.edit(foundUsername); //The part where it asks you to add the Code
          const collector2 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
            max: "1",
            maxMatches: "1",
            time: "200000",
          }); // Collector2
          collector2.on("collect", async (mag) => {
            if (
              mag.content.includes("done") & mag.content.includes("done") &&
              mag.author.id == message.author.id
            ) {
              const fetchingBlurb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("0x00e5ff")
                .setTitle("Fetching..")
                .setDescription(
                  "Fetching your emojis, please wait as I am going to fetch it."
                )
                .setFooter(
                  "Fetching..",
                  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/686639712869285946.gif?v=1"
                )
                .setTimestamp();
              sentMessage.edit(fetchingBlurb); //Checks the Blurb / Status
              setTimeout(function () {
                //Timeout Stuff
                rbx.getStatus(foundId).then((status) => {
                  //Check status
                  console.log(status); //Console.log the status
                  rbx.getBlurb(foundId).then((blurb) => {
                    // Checks the blurb
                    if (
                      status.includes(newString) ||
                      blurb.includes(newString)
                    ) {
                      // If code is in blurb procceds with operation
                      const completedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                        .setColor(0x00e5ff)
                        .setTitle("Verification completed!")
                        .setDescription(`You are now verified as ${m.content}`)

                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter(
                          "ClanSystems bot for group promotions",
                          "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755083118087766056/755139238839975968/yes.gif"
                        );
                      sentMessage.edit(completedEmbed); // Sent if user has put code
                      message.member.roles.add(
                        message.guild.roles.find((r) => r.name == "Verified")
                      ); // Add the users role
                      message.member.setNickname(m.content); // Sets the users nickname

                      const member = message.author;
                      userdata.findOne(
                        {
                          discordID: member.id,
                        },
                        (err, data) => {
                          if (!data) {
                            const newData = new userdata({
                              robloxID: foundId,
                              discord: message.author.username,
                              discordID: message.author.id,
                            });
                            newData.save().catch((err) => console.log(err));
                          } else {
                            return;
                          }
                        }
                      );
                    }
                  });
                }, 5000);
              });
            } else if (
              mag.content.includes("cancel") ||
              (mag.content.includes("Cancel") &&
                mag.author.id == message.author.id)
            ) {
              const cancelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x00e5ff)
                .setTitle("Verification canceled")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(
                  "ClanSystems bot for group promotions",
                  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755083118087766056/755139240232485035/no.gif"
                );
              sentMessage.edit(cancelEmbed); // If user says `Cancel`
              return;
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: This means `message.channel` does not contain what you think it does (it's undefined). Work backwards from there.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it, in my index file i passed in the bot client aswell and for some reason that messed it up, i dont know why but well its fixed now